# Sampling approach in >2 dimensions that keeps marginal probabilities (nearly) equal

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization

I've got a histogram of my data divided into a `3x3x3` cube ($X$, $Y$, and $Z$).

I need to sample stochastically from this cube such that my marginal distributions for $X$ are (nearly) equal, and the same for Y, and Z.

**Some of the bins will be empty.** Assume that all marginal distributions are represented by at least one sample.

Can I come up with a set of joint probabilities to sample from such that I maintain equality among marginal distributions (or as near to this goal as is possible based on the data distribution)?

The best approach I can think of is to minimize a loss function that is a set of square-losses measuring (1) the difference between marginal distributions, (2) measuring for marginals summing to 1, and (3) regularizing against large parameters (ideally the joints probabilities will remain as even as possible within constraints).

- Is there perhaps a closed form solution to the problem that I haven't thought of?
- Would a constrained optimization be better than modeling the constraints in a loss function? I worry that some constraints might not be achievable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using an optimization approach in which the parameters represent the sampling probability of each bin.

I define a loss function with the following 3 quadratic terms:

- Square error from one marginal to the next in a round robin
- Square error of $1$ minus the sum of each marginal distribution
- Tunable regularization on the square of the parameter size (ensuring that the joint probabilities are as uniform as possible for the data).